# How to use jQuery in javascript chrome bookmark code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, bookmarks

In google chrome you can put js code into a bookmark by using this pattern

```
javascript: (

    )();
```

What would be a way to use jQuery inside that js code?
Particularly this:

```
$('body *').not($('#content_container').parents().addBack()).css({visibility: 'hidden'});
```

Comment: It depends on the page you are visiting.  If it uses jQuery then you don't need to do anything special.  Otherwise you'll be adding a script to the document.  If you add jQuery to a page that already uses it...bad things could happen.

Comment: page does not use jQuery - actually its facebook ... I want wo run code in a bookmark to hide all elements except of the current post.

Answer (score 1):

to ensure jQuery is available, you would embed the minified library into your JavaScript bookmark function.
This is a bad idea, you are better off writing vanilla js, it will be smaller and anything you want to do with jQuery can be done with vanilla js